Runnig a simple model on PyTorch and Flask on NPU/GPU
My code is below: The code works when I run it on CPU however, when I move to a device such as NPU I get an error in the step when I try to move the tensor to the device tensor = tensor.to(device). The error message image is also attached below .
import io
import json
from torchvision import models
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import torch
import torch_npu

app = Flask(__name__)
imagenet_class_index = json.load(open('imagenet_class_index.json'))

# Load the pre-trained ResNet model and move it to the Ascend NPU if available


model = models.densenet121(weights=models.DenseNet121_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1)    
device = torch.device("npu" if torch_npu.npu.is_available() else "cpu")
print(f"Device selected: {device}")
model.to(device)
model.eval()

# Move the model to the selected device


def transform_image(image_bytes):
    my_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255),
                                        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                        transforms.ToTensor(),
                                        transforms.Normalize(
                                            [0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                            [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes)).convert('RGB')
    return my_transforms(image).unsqueeze(0)

def get_prediction(image_bytes):
   
    tensor = transform_image(image_bytes=image_bytes)
    tensor = tensor.to(device)  # Ensure the tensor is transferred to the correct device
    print(f"Tensor device: {tensor.device}")
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(tensor)
    _, y_hat = outputs.max(1)
    predicted_idx = str(y_hat.item())
    return imagenet_class_index[predicted_idx]

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No file provided'}), 400
    
    file = request.files['file']
    img_bytes = file.read()
    class_id, class_name = get_prediction(image_bytes=img_bytes)
    return jsonify({'class_id': class_id, 'class_name': class_name})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8088)



which is your target device? I mean huawei NPU or qualcomm NPU or etc?
